# The [lifestyle] tag is too vague. Can we burninate?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [lifestyle](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) tag currently has 16 questions, and they are about everything imaginable.

In vegan-oriented businesses and organisations "lifestyle" usually means anything vegans need an alternative product for that is *not* food, for example, shoes and bags (not leather), cosmetics (free from animal-derived ingredients and not tested on animals), even travel guides.

Even if our lifestyle tag were to be used to mean that (which is not particularly intuitive, and not a good idea in my opinion), I think it would cover too much, and at the moment it is on all kinds of other stuff like:

- [Are natality rates lower among vegans?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-natality-rates-lower-among-vegans)
- [How can I ask my guests to eat vegan when I host them?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/599/how-can-i-ask-my-guests-to-eat-vegan-when-i-host-them)

At the moment this tag defines nothing whatsoever. Its contents are completely random.

What should we do about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I would argue for burnination.** I agree with you that there is no meaning this tag conveys whatsoever. Vegetarianism itself is a [lifestyle](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle). No need to have a tag for it.

I can imagine we could also specify the scope of the tag for this site and make it actually mean something but enforcing this on new questions would likely prove to be a headache and not one that is, in my opinion, worth it.

Comment: +1 because what he said.  I never thought of diet as separate from lifestyle.